# How to click button using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString in cocoa

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, uiwebview

I want to click on button automatically using UIWebview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString
HTML Source

```
<input type="image" src="image.gif" alt="sign-in" onclick="return check_form();" value=" Enter " tabindex="3"/>
```

I tried directly calling function name but it is not working. Can anyone help me ?

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"check_form()"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The piece of JavaScript you are looking for is:

`document.getElementById("check_form_button").click();`

Make sure to add `id="check_form_button"` to your button.